# Storyboard animation can't pause in WPF after add Timeline.DesiredFrameRate

Tags: c#, wpf, .net-4.0

I have a `Storyboard`, I want to change `Tag` element in every 10 seoconds:

```
  <Storyboard x:Key="sbSmallAd" Duration="0:0:20" RepeatBehavior="Forever">
        <StringAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="Tag">
            <DiscreteStringKeyFrame Value="1" KeyTime="0:0:0" />
            <DiscreteStringKeyFrame Value="2" KeyTime="0:0:10" />
        </StringAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
    </Storyboard>
```

I want to use it in my `Image`:

```
 <Grid x:Name="grdAd" PreviewMouseDown="Grid_Ad_PreviewMouseDown" Background="Transparent" Visibility="Collapsed">
       <Image x:Name="imgAd"  PreviewMouseDown="Grid_Ad_PreviewMouseDown"/>
 </Grid>
```

Then I begen the animation in code behind:

```
// Start the code
private Storyboard adStoryboard = null;
public void Start()
{
  grdAd.Visibility = Visibility.Visible;
  if (null == adStoryboard)
  {
      adStoryboard = (Storyboard)this.FindResource("sbSmallAd");
      // Some people said we must set second parameter isControllable set to 
      // true for pause it, I did but not working
      adStoryboard.Begin(imgAd, true);
  }
  else
  {
      adStoryboard.Resume(imgAd);
  }
}
```

Also I want the animation `Pause`, when I click it:

```
private void Grid_Ad_PreviewMouseDown(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
{
   grdAd.Visibility = Visibility.Collapsed;
   adStoryboard.Pause(imgAd);
}
```

But the problem is, even I already `Pause` the animation, the `Tag` element will still keep changeing, I tried too much time for this, but I can't understand. Is there any one know what is going on here?  Thanks.

I'm using: `.Net4` with `Visual Studio 2017`

**Update 1:**

Some friend tell me that `they can't reappear this problem`, because my project too big for show the all code, for a example I made a new project. `Then I can't reappear the problem too.....`
I finnaly find out I really miss 1 line code:

```
adStoryboard.SetValue(Storyboard.DesiredFrameRateProperty, 1);
```

Or, put it in to the XAML:

```
<Storyboard x:Key="sbSmallAd" Timeline.DesiredFrameRate="1" Duration="0:0:20" RepeatBehavior="Forever">
    <StringAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="Tag">
          <DiscreteStringKeyFrame Value="1" KeyTime="0:0:0" />
          <DiscreteStringKeyFrame Value="2" KeyTime="0:0:10" />
    </StringAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
</Storyboard>
```

Also I find out the solution for it, just put the `Duration` and the `RepeatBehavior` from `Storyboard` to `StringAnimationUsingKeyFrames`:

```
<Storyboard x:Key="sbSmallAd" Timeline.DesiredFrameRate="1">
    <StringAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="Tag" Duration="0:0:20" RepeatBehavior="Forever">
          <DiscreteStringKeyFrame Value="1" KeyTime="0:0:0" />
          <DiscreteStringKeyFrame Value="2" KeyTime="0:0:10" />
    </StringAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
</Storyboard>
```

**But**, this solution will cause another problem: If after the `Value` change to `2` I wait 5 seconds and `Pause` it, and wait to 10 second, `Resume` it , the `Value` change to `1`, not as I expected: still show `2` for another `5` seconnds.

I'm not close this Question, because I still want to know why `Timeline.DesiredFrameRate="1"`
cause this probme. Also I want to know why my solusion not real `Resume` it as I expected.

I sincerely apologize everyone that I miss that `problem` code when I first wrote the question. Also **I change the question title** from:

> Storyboard animation can't pause in WPF

to:

> Storyboard animation can't pause in WPF after add
>   Timeline.DesiredFrameRate

That's only for help the other people find this kind of problem, I hope some friends that join this problem earlier could understand.

Comment: I copied the code you have here, and for me it works. When I click on the image, the animation stops, and the Tag does not get changed anymore. Can you describe the steps to reproduce your issue with the code you have given?

Comment: @LupuSilviu, I see the property by visual studio 2017, and I can clearly could see it still changing after I pause it in every 10 seconds. Are you using .net4? You could also don't `Resume` it after you next time display it, then you could know it paused or not.

Comment: Yes. I bound the Tag to a TextBlock to see how it changes. Try the same thing  `<TextBlock Grid.Row="1" Text="{Binding Tag, Mode=OneWay, ElementName=imgAd}"/>` . I reduced the time to 1 second and 2 seconds, so not to way 20 seconds. This should not impact the way the animation works, only the speed of the change.

Comment: Same as @LupuSilviu here, Tag property is not updated after clicking on the Image. Tried with .Net 4.6 and .Net 4, same result.

Comment: @qakmak I think you did not post your entire code otherwise it works fine for everyone. Please post all of your code as no one can reproduce the issue with given code.